# How to find the intersection of two `path3[]`

Tags: intersections, asymptote

I'm using **Asymptote** to draw some figures and I need to put a dot on the intersection of two `path3[]` but the command `intersectionpoint()` doesn't work for `path3[]`. What can I do?

Comment: I am not familiar with this package but those who are will need to see a minimum working example in order to trouble shot your problem.  This includes the preamble, begin and end document, and a small re-creation of the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Built-in three-dimensional version of the 
function `intersectionpoints` returns an array of intersection points 
of the two `3d` paths. To get the intersections 
of two `path3[]` arrays, 
a simple function `intersectionpoints3` can be used,
that checks and accumulates all combinations of the intersection points:

```
import three;
currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(-5,1.5,4),up=Y,target=O,zoom=1);

triple[] intersectionpoints3(path3[] p,path3[] q){
  triple[] r=new triple[];
  triple[] s;
  for(path3 pk:p){
    for(path3 qj:q){
      s=intersectionpoints(pk,qj);
      if(s.length>0)r.append(s);
    }
  }
  return r;
} 

size(200);
path3[] p=box(O,(1,1,1));
path3[] q=(-0.5,0,0.5)--(1.5,0,0.5)..(2,0.5,0.5)..(1.5,1,0.5)
   ^^(1.5,1,0.5)--(-0.5,1,0.5)..(-1,0.5,0.5)..(-0.5,0,0.5);

draw(p,darkblue);
draw(q,orange);

dot(intersectionpoints3(p,q),red);
```